# Why does this client-side JS (JQuery, regex) work on some domains but not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dns

This is really bizarre.  I have some purely client-side JS that was working fine on my server, but then stopped working when I moved the site to my client's site.

```
<select class="langset">
    <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
    <option value="kr">한국어</option>
    option value="cn">中文</option>
</select>
```

And here's my JS:

```
$('.langset').change(function() { 
//handle nav between different languages
    console.log('changed');
    window.location.href = document.URL.replace(/\/\w\w\//, "/"+$(this).val()+"/");
});
```

This allows me to move between corresponding pages like:

http://clientname.mysite.net/en/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval

http://clientname.mysite.net/kr/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval

It works fine on my server.  On their server, it works for

http://www.clientname.net/en/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval

but not for

http://clientname.net/en/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval

The bizarre thing is that the change event doesn't even fire (I don't get the console log) without the www hostname prepended.

Verrrry puzzled. I'm blaming my regex, but it looks fine to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work with : `window.location.href = document.URL.replace(/\/\w\w\w\//, "/"+$(this).val()+"/");` on [http://clientname.net/en/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval](http://clientname.net/en/somefolder/somepage.php?somearg=someval)

Comment: How could this be a regex issue if you already know that your event isn't being fired?